# Match version numbers using regex while excluding entries with underscore

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match release versions using regex but exclude any string or group in a string that might have underscore after version number.
The pattern is n.n(optionally additional .n) and nothing else, aka major.minor version and additionally build version.
Update: Additionally if possible, letters can be allowed but only after n.n or n.n.n for example n.na or n.n.na but not any other combination.

For example:

```
1.2.3
10.2.4
10.20.5
10.20.323
1.20.30
1.2.33
1.0
1.2a
1.1.2a
1.22_UAT_2
1.10.2_TEST1
1.2_UAT2
2.0_LIVE_2_
a line with text which has 1.2 or then 1.2.1 but then 1.2.1_UAT2 or 1.3_TEST also include version as 1.3a or 1.4.1b but not 1.2a_UAT3 and not 1.2b_1 or 1.2.3a_b
```

Should return:

```
1.2.3
10.2.4
10.20.5
10.20.323
1.20.30
1.2.33
1.0
1.2a
1.1.2a
1.2
1.2.1
1.3a
1.4.1b
```

Comment: You said, "a line with text...also exclude such version as 1.2a or 1.2.1b", but then you say`'1.2'` and `'1.2.1'` are among the values to be returned. What if an entry were `'1.2a_1'` or `'1.2a_b'`? Please clarify (by editing).

Comment: Hi Cary, I have edited original question now to clarify the points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `^([\d\.]*\n)`:

`( )` marks a group

`^` is used to search at the start of a Line

`[\d\.]*` matches any digit or `.`, `*` matches any amount of those

`\n` matches newline (the end of a line)

In other words: The expression matches any combination of digits or `.` that ranges from the start of the line to the end of the line

However i am confused why your "Should return" block contains `1.2.1` in the last line, could you explain why `1.2.1` should be matched?

Comment: Hi @Hein,

in last line ```1.2.1``` should be returned but ```1.2.1_UAT2``` should not, that is a requirement. Apologies for not making it clear. I have updated the description to reflect this.

Comment: I have changed the Regex Expression to `\b[\d\.]+(?=[ \n])`, does this cover everything you need?

Comment: Hi Hein, thank you for providing this pattern, it does indeed achieve the requirement I need and also improved on one point from pattern @lemon provided, which is to remove the spaces before and after the release numbers in a long string (last line test example)

Comment: Your regex (and also the revised one in your comment) matches `'1..1..'` and does not match `1.2` in `'1.2a'`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland your first point is correct, however this case should never come up, since all of the inputs are still valid version numbers, an ```1..1..``` is not a valid version number.

Comment: @CarySwoveland to answer your second point, that is intended behavior. If you compare the provided examples with the expected results you can see that. kosdos only wants to match the versions which contain only digits and periods

Comment: You may be right about what the OP wants to match but that is inconsistent with the title and the examples. The OP needs to clarify.

Comment: Hi, I have went over my question and clarified the inconsistencies. Originally I just wanted to have numbers but after discussion with @lemon I realised that one letter after release number should be allowed too.

Comment: I can see that @lemon pattern mentioned in comments to his answer is the closest match to what I was looking for, with one slight issue, in a long text string when versions are matched, it also picks up empty spaces before and after.
Pattern Hein provided does not include the spaces but needs to add a letter after version.
Could we consolidate the two answers together?

Comment: I just had a look and with updating Hein's pattern to ```\b[\d\.]+[A-Za-z]*(?=[ \n])``` it seems to be returning what I require but it also includes versions such as 1.2aabc which should be excluded

Comment: Hello kosdos, that's not quite right, your proposal also matches ```1.1.2ab```. Changing it to `\b[\d\.]+[A-Za-z]?(?=[ \n])` does what you want. The `?`allows only one or zero letters

Comment: Hi Hein, yes was just about to send an update, that is looking like exactly the pattern I need.
Thanks for you help, also thanks @CarySwoveland for pointing out inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1):

You can match every digit and dot `[\d\.]+`, which group is found

- after a boundary or a space `(\b|\s)`
- before an end of line character or a space `(\s|$)`

Here's the complete regex:

```
(\b|\s)([\d\.]+)(\s|$)
```

If you want a more strict version, that avoids matching versions that have less than two numbers and more than three, you can instead use the following:

```
(\b|\s)([\d]+\.[\d]+([\.]+[\d]+)?)(\s|$)
```

In order to retrieve the version, you can access Group 2 for both regex.

Does it work for your cases?

Comment: Hi @lemon,

Thank you for such rapid reply, I have tried this pattern and it does indeed achieve the expected behaviour with one slight issue - when the match is in a long string (the last test in description), it returns the spaces before and after the release number, is it possible to remove those?
Additionally, can this pattern be improved to exclude anything that includes letters after each part, for example I'd like to exclude entries such as 1.1a or 1.1.1a?
Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Updated with the letters after the version. Also now you're able to access the version using the reference to Group 2. Does it solve your problem? @kosdos

Comment: After running tests I can see following issues:
```1.2a
1.2.1a```
are included, and should not be

```what about a line with text and then suddenly 1.2 or then we have 1.2.1 but then we have 1.2.1_UAT2 or 1.3_TEST and then we have 1.2a and 1.2a_TEST```
Pattern still works as and 1.2a_TEST is exluded as expected, but 1.2a is included and should not be.

Thanks @lemon

Comment: Mmh probably I'm not understanding your last requirement on versions with letters: `(\b|\s)([\d\.]+)(\s|$)` doesn't match `1.2a` while `(\b|\s)([\d\.]+[A-Za-z]*)(\s|$)` does match `1.2a`. Can you update your question with sample cases, indicating what should be matched? @kosdos

Comment: Hi @lemon, no version number should match either underscores or having a letter past n.n pattern. I have updated the description to make it more clear with the additional requirements

Comment: Thanks for making it clear! I've updated my answer accordingly, does it meet your text structure? @kosdos

Comment: Thank you @Lemon, this is what I was looking for in this specific scenario. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can attempt to match the regular expression with the case-indifferent flag set.

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+)+(?![_\d.]|[a-z][a-z\d]*_)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2d7wJ5/1)

The expression contains the following elements.

```
^           # match beginning of string
\d+         # match >= 1 digits
(?:         # begin non-capture group
  \.\d+     # match a period followed by >= 1 digits
)+          # end non-capture group and execute it >= 1 times
(?!         # begin negative lookahead
  [_\d.]    # match an underscore, digit or period
|           # or
  [a-z]     # match a letter
  [a-z\d]*  # match >= 0 letters or digits
  _         # match underscore
)
```

Comment: This matches ```1.2``` in ```1.2a``` but the requirement is "exclude any string or group in a string that might have underscore or letter after version number"

Comment: @Hein, yes, I know, but `'1.2'` is included among "should return" and the only string containing that is `'1.2a'`. Also, I don't know where the "should return" `'1.2.1'` came from. I've asked the OP to clarify.

Comment: both of the "should return" that you mention come from the first half of the last line: "a line with text which has 1.2 or then 1.2.1 but then...". I admit this last line is worded poorly, but in my opinion the requirement is still clear: OP wants to return version numbers which contain only digits and periods, no other characters at the end (like `1.2a` has), no matter where in the line it appears

Comment: Hi Cary, I have made an edit to the question in order to clarify what should be returned. Originally I only wanted numbers and nothing included if it has underscore. Later realised we might have scenarios where a/b/c might be used after n.n or n.n.n but we should only pick up one character matches and still ignore if theres underscores in a line, or additional a/b/c..

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
\b\d+(?:\.\d+)*[a-zA-Z]*(?!\S)
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)*` Match 1+ digits and optionally repeat matching a dot and 1+ digits
- `[a-zA-Z]*` Match optional chars a-zA-Z
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JM6DJ7/1).